# How to inject @Values in unit (or integration) tests without writing out temporary files

Tags: java, spring

We have a Spring-based project whose unit tests create temporary properties files to send into application contexts like:

```
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = applicationContext.getBean(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);
    propertyConfigurer.setLocation(new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource("file:" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Is there a better way to send in a set of properties (that get injected as `@Value`s) other than writing out temporary files and then reading them in this way?

Obviously I want the properties to only survive for the duration of the test, so cramming them into `System.properties` is perhaps not appropriate.

Comment: Can you provide more detail please. Also are you trying to dynamically setup the property file name? Can you utilize classpath or test class name to help you?

Comment: I have `@Component`s that have `@Value` injections, and I want to set the values for those on each test run; the code I inherited used temp files for this but I want to know if there is a more direct way.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but:

> Obviously I want the properties to only survive for the duration of
>   the test, so cramming them into System.properties is perhaps not
>   appropriate.

Both Maven and Ant can run Junit in different fork modes. If you select `per-test`, then a new VM will be started for each test and the above doesn't apply.

I'm not saying that's what you should do, just trying to make the picture complete :-)

Comment: True, that helps, though it also slows down the test suite (if I remember correctly.) Might have to go that route, though.